# I using to 'io()' in closed function

Tags: node.js

i'm japanese.i can't write perfect in English that yours understand.
please teach me. i using to 'io()' in closed function. but, i want to use 'io()' as global function.i don't know the risk that  if using to 'io()' as global function. please teach me that.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read [ask] to learn how to make great questions to be answer by the community!

Comment: oh thank you !! i'm seem happy that be sent me your advice.